# Best method of secure Objective-C iPhone login

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I wanted to know, the best methodology (with code sample please) of having a login feature on an iPhone application, that would connect to a server. I am assuming web service sending via SOAP isn't the safest.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With NSURLRequest / NSMutableURLRequest you can set up authentication using any method you like... here's an HTTP Basic example for getting some XML result.

```
  NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"]; // or POST or whatever
  [request setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
  NSString * userID = @"hello";
  NSString * password = @"world";
  NSString * authStr = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", userID, password] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64Encoding];
  [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Basic %@", authStr] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

You'll need to read up on HTTP authentication techniques to know what to do to talk to your specific server, but there's nothing wrong with using HTTPS (SSL) + Basic, it's secure.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to protect? A good start is to use HTTPS to transfer login information to the web service. You'll still need to secure the web service, but at least the users will be secure against snooping and man-in-the-middle attacks.